How to make curl in Windows use a variable as part of a path
Edit: I'm doing all of this in WIndows PoweShell.
I was doing the tutorial for using kubernetes (one of the ones in kubernetes.io) and it tells you to use:
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}')

I had to remove the "export" for it to work in windows (also had to remove the line break for some reason, but it worked after that), so the command was:
$POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{end}}')

It worked, and if I typed:
$POD_NAME

I got the correct pod name.
The problem came from the next step where I had to use:
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME:8080/proxy/

Here, it was unable to resolve the url, while if I just replaced $POD_NAME with the text in the variable, it worked just fine.
I was wondering if there is a way to make it work (as in making the variable name be substituted by it's content when interpreting the command).
Not sure if it helps, but this is the error message:
curl : { "kind": "Status", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": {}, "status": "Failure", "message": "pods \"proxy\" not found", "reason": "NotFound", "details": { "name": "proxy",  "kind": "pods" }, "code": 404 }  
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1  
+ curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME:8 ...  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Edit: I've tried a little bit more, and it seems the problem is that powershell interprets $POD_NAME:8080 as if it was the name of the variable (instead of just $POD_NAME and considering :8080 as part of the string that's not part of the variable). Still I would like to know id there's a way to do this instead of having to create a new string by adding the first part (before the 8080) to the second part.

I've tried %POD_NAME%, %$POD_NAME%, $%POD_NAME% and all of them with double %, but I can't seem to make any of them work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, it looks like this:
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/%POD_NAME%:8080/proxy


I was doing the tutorial for using kubernetes (one of the ones in
kubernetes.io) and it tells you to use:
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}') 

I had to remove the "export" for it to work in windows (also had to
remove the line break for some reason, but it worked after that), so
the command was: $POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -o go-template
--template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{end}}')
It worked, and if I typed: $POD_NAME I got the correct pod name. The
problem came from the next step where I had to use:
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME:8080/proxy/

Here, it was unable to resolve the url, while if I just replaced
$POD_NAME with the text in the variable, it worked just fine. I was
wondering if there is a way to make it work (as in making the variable
name be substituted by it's content when interpreting the command).
Not sure if it helps, but this is the error message:
curl : { "kind": "Status", "apiVersion": "v1", "metadata": {}, "status": "Failure", "message": "pods \"proxy\" not found", "reason":

"NotFound", "details": { "name": "proxy", "kind": "pods" }, "code":
404 } En línea: 1 Carácter: 1 + curl
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME:8 ... +
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation:
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.

I see what's happening here. When you use $POD_NAME in the curl command, it isn't getting replaced by its value. This issue often arises from how the shell handles variable interpolation.
In PowerShell, which it looks like you might be using, you need to use different syntax for variable interpolation. Here’s how you can make it work:
$POD_NAME = $(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{end}}')
curl "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME:8080/proxy/"


Why did you copy OP's question to your answer? Did you copied this to a LLM ?

Please learn to use the {} tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct code/data/output/errMsg formatting.  AND I agree that there is no reason to include the whole question in your reply. Note the Block Quote option in the Edit menu when you need to include something from the original question.

The problem remains the same, it tries to take $POD_NAME:8080 as the variable name, as / is considered to be the end of the variable, but : isn't.

Does Powershell support a syntax to isolate variable names as do most *nix shells, i.e. ${POD_NAME}:8080 ? Good luck.
